# maybe lost funds

Tags: transaction, wallet, iota-recovery

Sometime in Q4 2017 I sent my MIOTA to the wallet. I verified then that the funds had arrived. Now I am logging in and the balance says 0. I am having a hard time interpreting the transaction history. Can someone take a look?
My address is 
LKQGBV9MCMPVJTTEJMPSAZNRFGMIWJSNSRQVLXTHSXEQQO9FGYCVAEPZBI9EWQUVOFVYCBFVZNUJPTXIDLCDUNBPRD

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't used an online seed generator, most likely your funds are safe. Are there any outgoing Txs in the history of your wallet?

Two days ago, there was a snapshot. Log into your wallet with your seed, then go to the receive section and generate new addresses. Keep on generating receive addresses until your balance is restored.

Also have a look at this well written post by Ralf Rottmann (IF Board of Directors) to get a good understanding of what a snapshot is and what it does. Here: https://medium.com/@ralf/prepare-for-the-january-28-2018-iota-snapshot-10f565b371ab

If this doesn't help, keep us updated here.

Answer (score 0):

If you are certain that your seed has not been compromised, then either there was a [snapshot](https://www.reddit.com/r/iota/wiki/faq#wiki_why_does_balance_appear_to_be_0_after_a_snapshot.3F) or you may just be connected to an unsynced node. The last snapshot was on April 29th, 2018, so if you haven't accessed your wallet since then, then please read [this post](https://forum.helloiota.com/588/Help-My-IOTA-balance-is-zero-steps-to-help-you-find-your-balance-v254?PageIndex=1) for necessary steps to take with the [most current version of the light wallet](https://github.com/iotaledger/wallet/releases) to recover your balance. Please note that everyone had to go through this. In the case of a bad node, you may also look up a node in this [list of healthy nodes](http://iota-nodes.net/) to connect to. You'll need to be connected to a healthy node regardless of your situation.